# SQL Replication Running ALTER VIEW against a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-replication, merge-replication

I have SQL Server Replication running between a Publisher and 2 subscribers.

**Publisher:** Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5538.0 (X64) 
    Apr  3 2015 14:50:02 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
    Workgroup Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7600: ) (VM)

**Subscriber:** Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5538.0 (X64) 
    Apr  3 2015 14:50:02 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (VM)

The server containing the subscriber database failed and had to be rebuilt. I restored the replication with the subscriber database and everything ran fine for about a day.

Now I am receiving the error: **"Cannot perform alter on 'dbo.MyTableName' because it is an incompatible object type."**

I ran SQL Profiler and found that immediately following a series of calls to sp_MSunmarkschemaobject. It is trying to run an ALTER VIEW dbo.MyTableName statement.

I've verified that dbo.MyTableName is a table not a view on both the Publisher and the Subscriber.

A little background, MyTableName was originally a view in the database, but was converted to a table, but this was over 3 years ago and replication had been working fine until the server went down.

Also of note is there is a second subscriber where everything is working fine.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: can you just reinitialize the subscriber for now?

Comment: I've tried and this is the message I get when trying to reinitialize. I'm also trying to setup a second subscriber on a empty database on the same server to see if I can get that working, but it fails at the very end and then gives the error message: **"The Merge Agent failed after detecting that retention-based metadata cleanup has deleted metadata at the Publisher for changes not yet sent to the Subscriber. "**